# Problem with Flyway - cannot access to SYSCAT.TABLES

Tags: quarkus, flyway, db2-zos

I have a problem with Flyway

My Quarkus project fails to start due to this error

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.SCHEMATA, DRIVER=4.31.10`

That's because I can't access to SYSCAT.TABLES with my credentials

How can i bypass this control?

In my Quarkus project I've a DB2 zOS connection, but I can't create table on the schema with my credential
So, I ask to create a custom FLYWAY table and i set this custom name on application.properties

```
quarkus.flyway.table=CUSTOM_FLYWAY_TABLE_NAME

quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=true #this to load data with SQL script
```

I also ask to create other tables, then I want to load data with SQL script by Flyway

I tried with custom table name, but nothing happens

Comment: SYSCAT is the DB2 LUW catalog. With DB2 z/OS the catalog resides in SYSIBM, e.g. SYSIBM.SYSTABLES.

Comment: @piet.t thanks for answer. And how can I specify this difference?

 _______ quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:otel:db2://hostname:port/database:currentSchema=IDRS;
 _______ quarkus.datasource.username=${DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
 _______ quarkus.datasource.password=${DATASOURCE_PWD}
 _______ quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect

 _______ quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=true
 _______ quarkus.flyway.repair-at-start=false
 _______ quarkus.flyway.clean-at-start=false
 _______ quarkus.flyway.table=I8DHAW_FLYWAY_SH

this is my application.properties

Comment: Try specifying a different hibernate dialect. Your are using DB2 for AS400 which is an even different beast than the two I mentioned before. Try with org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect or org.hibernate.dialect.DB2zDialect depending on the Quarkus/Hibernate-version.

Comment: @piet.t I've tried with both, but nothing change. Always this error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.SCHEMATA, DRIVER=4.31.10

Comment: Seems there is no full DB2 z/OS-support with flyway: https://brunomendola.github.io/flywaydb.org/documentation/database/db2zos "Create Schema - is not supported in db2 on zOS"

Comment: But I don't need to create a new schema. I have my tables on a created schema, and all of them are created. I need to use Flyway to load data into this tables. I think Flyway implicitly search this SYSCAT.SCHEMATA